# Is there an equation for an ‘erratic’ sine wave?

Tags: trigonometric-series

Instead a regularly repeating sine wave, consider a flat line which has a single full sine wave every 3 wavelengths.  Does this have a simple expression that can be graphed without specifying domains?

EDIT: Clarification for comments below. I am looking for a fully differentiable function that has a flat line with a full sine wave every 3 wavelengths. Modulo functions as well as composite functions are not what I am looking for. Rather, I am thinking about a fourier series which sums to the desired function but I do not know how to derive it.

Comment: What functions are you willing to use? For example, will you consider answers that use the modulo operator or the step function?

Comment: Do you mean one full sine wave followed by two wavelengths of $0$?

Comment: Three wavelengths followed by a period of zero amplitude?

Comment: 2 periods of zero and then a full wavelength. OR a full sine wave followed by 2 periods of 'zero'